# Better to use 1 or multiple database tables?

Tags: database, microsoft-access

I am experimenting with databases (using Access currently, as i have it through work).  To get acquainted, I am making a database to log catches on my fishing trips.  There are several "categories" of information, such as "fish info" (which would include species, weight, and length) and "location info" (includes name of the lake and GPS coordinates).  Other conditions such as the date/time and various weather conditions would also be in there.

I understand that databases are especially good for situations where an entry in one table could relate to multiple entries in a second table.  However, in my use case, a single fish will not have multiple locations, or multiple datetimes/weather conditions.

So my question is, should I be using multiple tables, and break them up according to "category"?  Or is it best practice to use one table, since no entry in any table will ever correspond to multiple entries in another table?

Thanks!

Comment: The point of having multiple tables is to reduce the same duplicated information and use flexible constraints. You probably want to read database normalization rules to get understand it better. I see at least one table that can be linked as one-to-many, it is  `species` that should have unique and indexed properties. The same probably going for location name....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend reading up on [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). It should shed some light on how you can lay out your database.

For example: a single lake probably always has the same name and coordinates. Why store them separately for every fish caught? Extract lake information into a separate table. Give each lake a unique name and coordinates. Let fish records reference lakes in their respective table. Searching by lake will be easier. Making typos will be harder and easier to fix.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation!  I've accepted yours as the official answer since it is clear a single table is not desirable.